# Linear model/lmList with nested/multiple group categories?

Tags: r, model, grouping

I am trying to build a model for monthly energy consumption based on weather, grouped by location (there are ~1100) AND year (I would like to do it from 2011-2014). The data is called `factin` and looks like this:

```
Store   Month      Days UPD     HD      CD      Year
1   August, 2013    31  6478.27 0.06    10.03   2013
1   September, 2013 30  6015.38 0.50    5.67    2013
1   October, 2013   31  5478.21 5.29    1.48    2013
1   November, 2013  30  5223.78 18.60   0.00    2013
1   December, 2013  31  5115.80 20.52   0.23    2013
6   January, 2011   31  4517.56 27.45   0.00    2011
6   February, 2011  28  4116.07 16.75   0.07    2011
6   March, 2011     31  3981.78 12.68   0.39    2011
6   April, 2011     30  4041.68 3.83    2.53    2011
6   May, 2011       31  4287.23 1.61    6.58    2011
```

And my model code, which just spits out 1 set of coefficients for all the years of each store, looks like this:

```
factout <- lmList(UPD ~ HD + CD | Store, factin)
```

My question is: is there any way I can get coefficients for each store AND year without creating a separate data frame for each year?

Comment: Create a data.frame column `interaction(Store, Year)` and use that as a grouping factor.

Comment: It threw back an error code... 'Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors'

Comment: @Roland that worked perfectly! Didn't realize interaction is a function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
     dat <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, text = "Store   Month year     Days UPD     HD      CD      Year
                  1   August 2013    31  6478.27 0.06    10.03   2013
                  1   September 2013 30  6015.38 0.50    5.67    2013
                  1   October 2013   31  5478.21 5.29    1.48    2013
                  1   November 2013  30  5223.78 18.60   0.00    2013
                  1   December 2013  31  5115.80 20.52   0.23    2013
                  6   January 2011   31  4517.56 27.45   0.00    2011
                  6   February 2011  28  4116.07 16.75   0.07    2011
                  6   March 2011     31  3981.78 12.68   0.39    2011
                  6   April 2011     30  4041.68 3.83    2.53    2011
                  6   May 2011       31  4287.23 1.61    6.58    2011")

factout <- lmList(UPD ~ HD + CD | Store, dat)



data.frame(Store = unique(dat$Store), summary(factout)$coef[1:2,1,1:3])

  (Intercept)        HD       CD
1    5405.108 -12.90986 107.2061
6    3581.307  32.93137 102.9780
```